How to make Laravel Reverb work on IIS server?
I have laravel 11 api only project. In the project I've integrated Laravel Reverb to make socket communication between Backend and Frontend. Frontend was developed in Vite/React. Both Backend and Frontend are running on the same server but still in decoupled architecture.
When the project is running locally Reverb is working fine as I can broadcast event from the backend and receive the data in the frontend through private channel.
This is my settings for Reverb in the Backend.
REVERB_APP_ID={*****}
REVERB_APP_KEY={*****}
REVERB_APP_SECRET={*****}
REVERB_HOST="localhost"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

And this is the settings for Reverb in the Frontend.
VITE_REVERB_APP_ID={*****}
VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY={*****}
VITE_REVERB_APP_SECRET={******}
VITE_REVERB_HOST="localhost"
VITE_REVERB_PORT=8080
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME=http

Code to connect to the reverb websocket from the Frontend.
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

import Pusher from 'pusher-js'
import api from '../../utils/api'
window.Pusher = Pusher

const useEcho = () => {
    const [echoInstance, setEchoInstance] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const echo = new Echo({
          broadcaster: 'reverb',
          key: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY,
          authorizer: (channel) => {
            return {
                authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                    api.post('api/broadcasting/auth', {
                        socket_id: socketId,
                        channel_name: channel.name
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        callback(false, response.data);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                        callback(true, error);
                    });
                }
            };
          },
          wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_HOST,
          wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
          wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
          forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_REVERB_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
          enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
        })
        setEchoInstance(echo)
    }, [])

    return echoInstance
}

export default useEcho

To deploy to IIS server, I enabled websocket protocol in IIS configuration settings.
But websocket is not working yet. Is there any good reference how to config IIS to make reverb working?
Thank you in advance.

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/#flask-with-socketio You might read a few previous thread and see how to troubleshoot Python related WebSocket issues. Likely you need to disable compression.

But websocket is not working yet.  Is there an error message? And see the IIS logs for more information.
